# Sed - string substitution with groupings

Tags: command-line, sed, string

I have a largish directory with filenames formatted like

```
Some_Folder-(FOL001)-clean
```

what I'm trying to do is display the pattern between the brackets at the start like

```
FOL001 Some_Folder-(FOL001)-clean
```

so it can be piped into sort

---

So far what I have is

```
ls | sed -n -e 's/.*\(\-([A-Z]\{3,4\}[0-9]\{3,4\})-\)\(.*\)/\1 \t \0/p' | sort
```

which produces

```
-(FOL001)- Some_Folder-(FOL001)-clean
```

However, I don't want the "-(" and ")-" on the output of the first pattern, just the contents. I know I can run this through `sed` again to replace those characters, but wondered if it's possible to include it in the original expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the grouping parentheses inside the presented parentheses.
This would do:

`ls | sed -nre 's/.*-\(([A-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{3,4})\)-.*/\1 \t \0/p'|sort`

I also use `-r` for regexp, it's easier to write brackets and parentheses.

With this option, grouping parentheses are `(`,`)`, and actual parentheses are `\(`,`\)`

Comment: `-r` is only for GNU `sed`. Some BSDs have a `-E` option. Generally/POSIXly, `sed` only supports _basic_ regular expressions.

Comment: This answered the question (and explained it aswell). If I wanted to anything between that pattern, could I just have something like `-\((*)\)-`?

Comment: do you mean `-\((.*)\)-` ?
Anyway, sed command will print out the whole line, that's why it needs to replace the whole line with what you need to print out. Therefore, the `.*` at the beginning and the end are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/.*-(\([A-Z]\{3,4\}[0-9]\{3,4\}\))-.*/\1 &/p'
```

But if it's only for sorting, maybe you can just to:

```
ls | sort -t'(' -k2
```

Answer (score 1):

The first approach prepends the sorting string to each filename:

```
$ ls -1 | awk -F\( '{print $2 " "$1"("$2}' | sed 's/)-clean//' | sort -n
FOL001 iemeezei-(FOL001)-clean
FOL002 aghaitug-(FOL002)-clean
FOL003 ieghaeve-(FOL003)-clean
```

The second one I like better, because the filename stays the same. It adds a space to the "FOL" string, which can then used by `sort` as a delimiter, the second `sed` removes the space again. If the filenames contain spaced, you might want to decide for another delimiter (which then has to given to `sort` with `-t`):

```
$ ls -1 | sed 's/(FOL/& /' | sort -nk2 | sed 's/FOL /FOL/'
iemeezei-(FOL001)-clean
aghaitug-(FOL002)-clean
ieghaeve-(FOL003)-clean
```